# How do I delete files except some specific files passed as parameters?

Tags: shell-script, find, rm, arguments, parameter

The task is to write a shell script with n+1 arguments where the first one is the directory and the rest is the specified files and will delete all but specified files.

E.g. calling `rmexcept . '*.jpg' '*.png'`

```
cd $1
for i in “${@:2}”
do 
find . -type f -not -name $i -delete
done
```

Here is my attempt. However, it just only works with 1 specified file (e.g. `rmexcept . '*.jpg'`). If there are more than 1 file (e.g. `rmexcept . '*.jpg' '*.png'`), all the files are deleted. I can't figure out what went wrong since I believe I have created a for loop.

Comment: Of course, every png file is not a jpg file, so those disappear, then down the line. Since it's an assignment, what was taught recently, so that we might guide you in a productive direction?

Comment: Well, my recent lessons revolve around control structures (for, while, if, case, etc.), printf, expr, dirname and basename

Comment: @Theophrastus erm... that doesn't work out very well :(. I got 'mv: rename \*.pdf to /tmp/\*.pdf: No such file or directory' (say, I want to delete all but pdf files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (comments inline):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
set -f     # Prevent e.g. *.txt from being expanded here

dir=$1     # Get the target directory and
shift      # remove from list of args

cmd="find $dir -type f"
while (( "$#" ))              # While there are more arguments left
do
    cmd="$cmd -not -name $1"  # add to not match
    shift                     # and remove from list of arguments
done
cmd="$cmd -exec rm -i {} ;"   # finally execute rm on the remaining matches

echo $cmd  # Print the final find command
$cmd       # And execute it
```

I added `-i` to `rm` so that it asks before removing each file. But you can tweak that, of course.

Comment: This code won't finish the job if either of the resulting `find` and `rm` commands are longer than the number returned by`getconf ARG_MAX`.  See [*Bash command line and input limit*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit)

Answer (score 0):

1. Same mechanism as [*laenkeio*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516104/165517), but as a more minimal
   no-variable *POSIX* shell function:

   ```
   rmexcept(){ find "$1" $(shift; printf " -not -name %s" ${@}) -exec rm '{}' \; ;}
   ```

   The shell's `printf` command does the main work, instead of a `for`
   or `while` loop.
2. Using the `bash` shell, the `shift` can be replaced by a parameter
   expansion:

   ```
   rmexcept(){ find "$1" $(printf " -not -name %s" ${@:2}) -exec rm '{}' \; ;}
   ```

---

Note that neither function will finish the job if the resulting `find` or `rm` commands are longer than the number returned by `getconf ARG_MAX`. See: *[Bash command line and input limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit)*.